# Solutions For Elastic Search document Update For Multiple fields using JAVA Api Code

Tags: elasticsearch, java

An exampes that demonstrates how we update multiple fields on elastic search document

```
Map<String, Object> updateObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updateObject.put("field1", "updated value for fields1");
updateObject.put("field2", "updated value for fields2");
updateObject.put("field3", "updated value for fields3");            
Boolean meessage = client.prepareUpdate("indexName","indextype","documentId").setDoc(updateObject).setRefresh(true).execute().actionGet();
```

indexName will be your index name
IndexType will be your index type
documentId will be your documentId which is going to update
client is your ElasticSeach client for JAVA API

Comment: I don't understand.  What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is how to update multiple fields using JAVA api.

For that use `BulkRequestBuilder`

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

bulkRequest.add(client.prepareUpdate("indexName","indextype","documentId") 
                .setScript("ctx._source.field1=" + newValueField1));

bulkRequest.add(client.prepareUpdate("indexName","indextype","documentId") 
                .setScript("ctx._source.field2=" + newValueField2));

BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

By this you can update multiple values within document

Comment: Hardik.I just post the solutions for multiple field update for Elastic Search using JAVA API. As i dont see any option for topic there thats why i posted it in questions

Comment: Oh than you should specify on top that this is the solution of particular problem,and at the end this is the QA site..anyways..edit your question so that people avoids such mislead . If you mentioned so i would tried directly your posted solution ..!!!