# how to update multiple rows in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index in elastic search db.
i want to update the multiple rows whose date column matches a particular date.
I can see only updating multiple columns in [Solutions For Elastic Search document Update For Multiple fields using JAVA Api Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405003/solutions-for-elastic-search-document-update-for-multiple-fields-using-java-api)

Comment: You're probably looking for the [update-by-query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) plugin.

Comment: yes.I want to update one column based on other columns.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out based on the documentation of that plugin or do you need an example?

Comment: it will be helpful if you can show me with an example..Thanks in advance Val..